# By what factor to increase width/height of icon for different screens - Android

Tags: android

I am developing an app and I am testing it on `420dpi` device. However, I am keeping `dimen.xml` file and updating it *roughly* for different screen sizes. Since I don't know by what factor I should increase or decrease image on different screen sizes. I would like to know if there's any strategy or way to make it easier without having to test the app on different devices. Is there any cheatsheet?

for example, this is how I adjust the height for an icon. Obviously, I am just using rough estimates and find it hard to test (practically not possible) for every icon and font sizes.

**dimen.xml**

```
<dimen name="height_image_view_home" />
```

**dimen.xml (w360dp)**

```
<dimen name="height_image_view_home">50dp</dimen>
```

**dimen.xml (w600dp)**

```
<dimen name="height_image_view_home">90dp</dimen>
```

**dimen.xml (w720dp)**

```
<dimen name="height_image_view_home">150dp</dimen>
```

[image: image icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a library (in fact 2 libraries) that can help you achieve this without needing to create other layout resource files for other screen sizes — SDP and SSP libraries.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6' 
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

In a situation where you are supposed to use a margin of `8dp`, you can use `@dimen/_8sdp` instead.

For text size, you can use `@dimen_/14ssp` instead of `14sp`.

the size will be changed according to the device sizes and resolution.

Learn more about these [libraries](https://medium.com/@segunfrancis/how-to-build-for-different-android-screen-sizes-using-a-single-layout-resource-file-6e71ec3d9fcc)

Comment: actually, I am trying to avoid using libraries.  And I don't think this approach is recommended by android. Anyway thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: I am using these libraries on an industry level, what you are trying to do, the library will do that task in an efficient way, the only thing the android doesn't recommend this is that this library has a predefined size and the user cannot change them. but for us, this is doing our task in an efficient way, otherwise creating different resources for different screens will increase the size of the project, and duplicate code is hard to handle and to make updates.